# Episode of a sci-fi show in which the main character is stuck in space; he combines alien DNA with his own and starts asexually copying himself

Tags: story-identification, tv, space, clones

I saw this back in the 90's. I thought it might be from the newer *The Outer Limits* TV show, but can't find the episode.

From what I recall, a guy was stuck on Mars (or somewhere) and was going to die. He found some native alien lifeform and used its DNA to mutate his own to be able to survive. He then started making these tumors that came off his body and grew into a full copy of himself.

At the end, he had a team of them all working with him at the facility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is **"[The Joining](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667975/?ref_=kw_li_tt)"** (1998), S04E13 of *[The Outer Limits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112111/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)* (1995–2002).

From [The Outer Limits Wiki](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/The_Joining):

> When a transport ship crashes and wipes out the colony on Venus, Capt. Miles Davidow (C. Thomas Howell) was the sole survivor. But after he's rescued by a team that includes his fiancee, Kate Girard (Amanda Tapping), and Scott Perkins (Jeffrey Jones), it soon becomes clear that Davidow did not escape unscathed.

A supply ship crashes near a research outpost on Venus, compromising its structural integrity. Months later, a rescue ship arrives from Earth. Most of the researchers are already dead by the time they get there, but they find one unconscious survivor, Captain Miles Davidow.

Davidow is brought back to Earth, placed in quarantine, and asked to explain how he managed to last seven months with only three months worth of oxygen. His explanation is sketchy, and furthermore, he's now getting sick, as if Earth's environment doesn't agree with him.

It's discovered that subjecting him to radiation like that found on Venus improves his overall well-being, but it also triggers a bizarre reaction in his body: a mass of tissue spontaneously bursts out of his forearm and lands on the floor, while the wound on his arm heals in minutes.

The mass of tissue is found to contain the bone structure of an underdeveloped hand. Further radiation treatments trigger similar reactions in his body, with the tissue being expelled becoming more fully-developed each time, and it's established that he can regenerate severed body parts.

Davidow eventually reveals that he discovered slug-like creatures on Venus and injected himself with their DNA in order to survive in that environment as long as he did. Those creatures were capable of asexual reproduction through a form of mitosis, an ability he now shares.

He's regarded as a threat to Earth due to this ability and his rapid healing, but rather than execute him, the decision is made to return him to the outpost on Venus, where he can continue his research along with the duplicates of himself he naturally spawns in that environment.

Comment: The old Outer Limits even though it occasionally i think was banned for "scary" content in some market. But this 1990s OL would have sent the censors of the 1960s to hide under the covers.

Comment: This particular episode features some surprisingly horrific visuals for a '90s TV show. The self-replication process involves masses of tissue ripping their way out of the protagonist's body like a [Chestburster](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Chestburster) alien.

Comment: Yea I remember liking the horror elements to it.  Thanks!

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just updated it.

Comment: Didn't realize there was an outer limits wiki. Was looking at episode summaries on Wikipedia and IMDB, and it was much less clear. Thanks again!